# parent element on top of elements that need hover

Tags: html, css

i have a div (.wrapper) with a div(**.bloks**) and inside 20 divs (**.blok**) on a raster (5*5) with each 2 divs (**.front** and **.back** panel). The **.front** panel appear when not hovering and, you can guess.., the **.back** panel when hovering **.blok**.. this all works just fine :D

the problem is that div **.bloks** is appearing first and behind this big block(600xauto) the elements **.blok** see *ps#1*.

I have seen this a time ago and the fix.. but now it has flied my mind.

What i did try already:

- `.wrapper > .blok:hover`
- `.bloks > .blok:hover`
- (created .blok:before dim: 100pxx100px (.blok dim) content="" ) and
  use `.blok:hover:before`
- `.wrapper {pos:rel, z-index:0}` & `.bloks { pos:abs,z-index: 10 }` & `.blok {pos:rel, z-index: 10 }`

link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOBjRE

thanks in advance..

***ps#1:*** (rew arrow represent my mouse)

[image]

***ps#2:***
[image]

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Creepster);
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: black;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top center, #01011d, #000000);
}
.wrapper {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.bloks {
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.blok {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.blok:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: red;
}
.front,
.back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
front {
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bloks">
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your codepen, nothing happens on hover. According to your question the back panel should display on hover.

Comment: @Michael_B REALLY ?? :p that i my whole problem... read title.. parent element on top of elements that need hover.. thanks for your attention and time

Comment: *The .front panel appear when not hovering and, you can guess.., the .back panel when hovering .blok.. this all works just fine :D* it

Comment: @Michael_B the function for hovering works fine... (see PS#2)

Comment: Okay. Apologies if I misinterpreted. From your question it seems this is a stacking not a hover issue.

Comment: @Michael_B yes but i have no stacking.. normaly divs behave like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaWoXR for one reason or another it does not.. thanks again for your time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out or removing `pointer-events:none` from `.blok` `css`

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Creepster);
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: black;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top center, #01011d, #000000);
}
.wrapper {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.bloks {
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.blok {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.blok:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: red;
}
.front,
.back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bloks">
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blok">
      <div class="front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: totaly not seen that left.. it is a concept and did rebuild it 7 times... forgot to delete that line.. thanks (i need sleep)